# ¿Como tener una password del mismo estilo que con Jframe pero en java o sea por consola?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un formulario, en teoría era en Swing pero he teneido problemas con el serializa y deserializa y he decidio hacerlo sin Swing ya que no era obligatorio.
Entonces mi preguta es, es posible tener algo como el Password de Jframe osea que cuando tu metas la clave por consola salga astericos o cosas del estilo? os dejo mi clase Persona para que os hagais una idea aunque no es necesario y si es posible como se hace?

```
Public class Persona implements Serializable {

    private String usuario;
    private String password;
    private int edad;
    private int telefono;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    public Persona() {
        this.usuario = "";
        this.password = "";
        setEdad(edad);
        setTelefono(telefono);
    }

    public Persona(String usuario, String password, int edad, int telefono) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.password = password;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        if (this.edad < 110) {
            this.edad = edad;
        }
    }

    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        if (Integer.toString(telefono).length() == 9) {
            this.telefono = telefono;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo echarle un vistazo a este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22546432/8484418

Comment: La idea es buena pero no entiendo nada entre que mi ingles no es muy haya y que usa clases que no he visto jamas no se que hace y copiar y pegar sin sentido no es cuestion

Comment: Para eso esta el traducir de google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes intentar con `java.io.Console` y su método `readPassword`, pero con una pega (ver más abajo):

```
import java.io.Console;

public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console console = System.console();
        String pass = String.valueOf(console.readPassword());
    }

}
```

Si ejecutas este código desde Eclipse o algún otro IDE, te va a fallar porque `System.console()` te va a devolver null. Sin embargo el código te debería funcionar si compilas el jar y lo ejecutas desde una consola.

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que se supone que hace eso

Comment: Se supone que es código leería de la entrada estándar de la consola (generalmente lo que escribe el usuario por el teclado), pero sin escribir nada en la salida estándar (generalmente lo que se ve por pantalla en la consola) y lo guarda en la variable pass como un String. Es decir, que el usuario podría escribir en la consola su contraseña sin que se viese escrita y tu tendrías guardado en pass la contraseña para hacer lo que necesites con ella.

Comment: Yo cambiaría `console.readPassword("Ingresa tu clave:");` para mostrar un mensaje solicitando el código, ahora no es que va a fallar en un IDE que no hayas configurado bien, la frase correcta seria: te va a fallar al ejecutarlo en un IDE y solo va a funcionar cuando lo ejecutes manualmente por consola, esto es porque al ejecutarse en un IDE el programa no inicia con una consola asociada aun que así lo parezca.

Comment: vamos por partes, tengo la clase persona hay es donde meteria String contraseña =  String.valueOf(console.readPassword()) ? en le constructor  vacio o donde? 2º  console.readPassword("Ingresa tu clave:"); donde meto eso?

Comment: @RobertoEMoran edito la parte de la configuración el IDE.

Comment: @unknow Creo que ya eso se desvía de la pregunta original que era si se puede leer un password por consola y ya has visto que hay formas. Es difícil contestarte sin saber más de la aplicación. No sé donde vas a pedir ese password ni lo que vas a hacer con él después. Te animo a que intentes seguir con el programa con lo que te han respondido aquí, y si te atascas hagas otra pregunta dando más datos de lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: La pregunta no esta desviada la pregunta es como hacerlo . Tengo un main y quier poder pedir una contraseña y que salgan ***** o espacios en blanco

Comment: @unknow me parece que efectivamente tu pregunta ha sido contestada correctamente con esta respuesta. El tema de donde vas a utilizar el código para solicitar la contraseña y guardarla en una instancia de tu clase `Persona` se sale del ámbito de la pregunta original.

Comment: Donde voy a guardar no . a mi em poneis un codigo pero no em decis como se implanta ese codigo en mi programa que es lo que me interesa. mi problema es saber implementar ese codigo en mi programa por eso pregunto en el foro porque google tb me da el codigo. No te lo tomes a mal pero falta cosas en la pregimta

Comment: @unknow, pero tu pregunta está enfocada en como puedes introducir una contraseña por la consola sin que se muestre en texto plano, no en donde ejecutar el código que haría esto. Por otra parte, sería muy difícil ayudarte a definir en que lugar de tu programa ejecutar dicho código sin conocer el tuyo. Pero te puedo decir que ese código debes utilizarlo en el lugar donde solicites que ingresen la contraseña.